# Not a single-group function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
SELECT s.*,count(numeromodule) as nbrmodule from session58 s natural join module15;
```

Hi, i get this error:Not a single-group function

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use 'natural join`.  It uses the names of columns, and this can change over time, changing what the query does -- and causing it to suddenly break for no apparent reason.  I'd have a softer spot in my heart if it used explicit foreign key relationships, but it doesn't.

Second, the problem is the `s.*`.  Here is another way to do what you want:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*) from module15 m where s.col1 = m.col1 . . . ) as nbrmodule
from session58 s;
```

I don't know what the `join` conditions are (another reason not to use `natural join`).

Also, this will return `0` counts.  If you do not want them, you can filter them out using a subquery, or this `where` clause:

```
where exists (select 1 from module15 m where s.col1 = m.col1 . . . )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to list the required fields in the `group by section`, e.g.

```
SELECT s.f1,s.f2,count(numeromodule) as nbrmodule 
from session58 s natural join module15 group by s.f1,s.f2;`
```

Comment: i get no row selected @Dmitry Zaytsev

Comment: @todo in this case you have some join issue
you shouldn't use natural join 
try join tables first and then add `count`/`group by`
`select * from session58 s join module15 n  on (s.id=n.id)`